# Joda DateTime not giving the expected results

Tags: java, jodatime

Given a `DateTime` object at 31-March-2011 and this code:

```
DateTime temp1 = new DateTime(2011, 3, 31, 12, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime temp2 = temp1.plusMonths(1);
DateTime temp3 = temp2.plusMonths(1);
```

after the execution

```
temp1 = 2011-03-31T12:00:00.000+02:00
temp2 = 2011-04-30T12:00:00.000+02:00
temp3 = 2011-05-30T12:00:00.000+02:00
```

temp3 is wrong here.

Is that above correct. Am I doing a mistake?

Comment: **Why** do you think that `temp3` is wrong? Explain what you expected.

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no mistake here. You're adding one month twice, which means the second time you'll get the result of adding a month to the *possibly truncated* result of adding the first month.

April only has 30 days, which is why you're getting April 30th for `temp2` - and adding one month to April 30th gets you to May 30th.

If you want May 31st, use:

```
DateTime temp3 = temp1.plusMonths(2);
```

Basically, date and time arithmetic [gives "odd" results](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic.aspx) if you try to think of it in terms of associativity etc.